# Why the DispatcherServlet xml configuration file is not in the specified directory in this Spring MVC application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

I am studying a Spring MVC tutorial and I have some doubt related to the configuration of the provided sample application (it works fine).

So I have the following strange situation:

Into the **\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF** folder inside by project I have the **web.xml** file (ok, this is absolutely normal) and inside this file I have this configuration related to Spring MVC **DispatcherServlet**:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

So I would expect to find the **mvc-config.xml** configuration file inside the **/WEB-INF/classes/** folder but I have not a **classes** folder inside the **WEB-INF** directory. Searching inside my project I find that the **mvc-config.xml** file is inside the **\src\main\resources** folder, as you can see in this picture:

[image]

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: this is done by the eclipse. search all the files inside one of them you will find that eclipse treats classes folder your resource folder in the runtime. this has nothing to do with spring, its just IDE magic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to update that XML file directly into the classes folder.
If you know whatever there in the src folder will be going to the classes folder by default so if you update your xml file inside your src file development tool (eclipse etc..) will put it into the classes folder automatically.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In the web.xml it say that it is into the /WEB-INF/classes/ diretory but I have not this directory and this file is not inside a subdirectory of WEB-INF but it is into \src\main\resources

Comment: That's the same I mean to say. Don't worry regarding this. Once you compile and build your program it will automatically come at that location. That mean building tool will compile Java source code (from src folder) and put compiled classes files along with your mvc-config.xml file to the classes folder. Once you build the project go and check to file system you will find classes folder there.